# R's glmnet throwing "A and B inner dimensions must match", but they already do

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I should say that although I'm learning glmnet for this problem, I've used the same dataset with other methods and it has worked fine.

In this process, I split my data into training and test sets, all formatted as matrices, and glmnet builds the model without complaining. However, when I try to run a prediction on the holdout set, it throws the following error:

```
glmfit <- glmnet(train_x_mat,train_y_mat, alpha=1)
glmpred <- predict(glmfit, s=glmfit$lambda.1se, new = test_x_mat)
# output:
Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : 
Cholmod error 'A and B inner dimensions must match' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_ssmult.c, line 82
```

However, I know that `x_train` and `x_test` have the same number of columns:

```
ncol(test_x)
[1] 146
ncol(train_x)
[1] 146
```

I'm fairly new to glmnet; is there something more I need to do to make it cooperate?

### Edit:

Here are the dimensions. Apologies for posting the vectors originally. This may be more at the heart of it.

```
dim(train_x_mat)
[1] 1411  208
dim(test_x_mat)
[1] 352 204
```

Which is strange, because they are created this way:

```
train_x_mat <- sparse.model.matrix(~.-1, data = train_x, verbose = F)
test_x_mat <- sparse.model.matrix(~.-1, data = test_x, verbose = F)
```

Comment: I think the problem is that some factor-like variables are being split into their own columns in both matrices. However, if some states of a given variable are not represented in both the training and testing dataset, the respective matrix won't include them.

Comment: Dataset is pretty huge. But using ```setdiff(colnames(train_x_mat),colnames(test_x_mat))``` I found the troublemakers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else who's running into this problem even though it seems like they shouldn't be, the issue is specifically with R's `sparse.model.matrix`. It will separate each level of a factor and give it its own column. Thus, if your dataset isn't particularly large, your training data and testing data could have different columns.

**A solution**, then, is to either add extra, blank columns to whichever matrix needs them, or else remove the columns that aren't shared by both. Of course, if you're building a model and expecting new data, the former is preferable. But anyway, the whole problem is a sign that your dataset is too small for the job.